# Multiple conditions If statement python doesn't work

Tags: python

I can't find what's wrong but my next code doesn't work:

```
if finalsum!=0 and (x[0]!='-' or x[0]!='+'):
```

Do something...

I need to add 2 more conditions
If I try only one AND, the code works, if I add the OR, nothing happens.

Also I've tried few more ways to write it and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @gspr answer is good enough. Unless you want to add more details that clarify your problem in another way

Answer (score 4):

The `x[0]!='-' or x[0]!='+'` condition is vacuous. It is always true.

If `x[0]` is anything other than `'-'`, then first part of the condition is true, so the whole condition is true. If `x[0]` is anything other than `'+'`, such as for example `'-'`, then the second part of the condition is true, so the whole condition is true. Thus the whole condition is true nomatter the value of `x[0]`.